# What is the default path for graphs stored from pyplot using plt.savefig?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please, help me in finding the default path when savefig command is used.

Comment: surely just your current working directory? `import os, print os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) says for the *fname* parameter of *savefig()* function: *A string containing a path to a filename, or a Python file-like object, or possibly some backend-dependent object such as PdfPages.*
So that if you specify an *absolute* path it should be save exactly there!

```
# Example with absolute path
savefig("/tmp/myfig")
```

Otherwise if the specified path is *relative*, it has to be interpreted to your current directory (surely the one where you launch the python interpreter or more reliably as said by Woody Pride you may ensure that by calling [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd))

```
# Example with relative path (suppose you are currently in /home/john/mydir/)
savefig("../myfig")
```

In this situation the file will be saved in /home/john/ directory.

Other situations may arise depending on the object you pass to the function (see upper definition)...